# String concatenation with argument to git alias'ed command

Tags: git

Since I clone from a machine with a long name a few times a day, I would like to create an `git alias` command.

Instead of

```
$ git clone git://machine.with.name.i.always.mistype/with/same/dirs/here/REPO.git
```

I would like to use (e.g. alias `klone`)

```
$ git klone REPO.git
```

How can I concatenate `REPO.git` inside a `git alias` to the long host and default directory stem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[alias]
    klone = !sh -c 'git clone git://machine.with.name.i.always.mistype/with/same/dirs/here/$1' -
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Can't believe this was in front of my eyes in the manpage all the time. Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `-` sign at the end?

Comment: @dafnahaktana https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423501/what-does-sh-mean

Answer (score 1):

If you're not committed to that exact syntax, use a shell alias or function called "git-klone".  Using bash or another sh-derived shell:

```
git-klone()
{
    git clone git://machine.with.name.i.always.mistype/with/same/dirs/here/"$@"
}
```

Using csh or tcsh:

```
alias git-klone 'git clone git://machine.with.name.i.always.mistype/with/same/dirs/here/\!*'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also save yourself typing the base part of the URL by using the contruction in your Git's config:

```
[url "<actual url base>"]
  insteadOf = <other url base>
```

Say,

```
[url "git://machine.with.name.i.always.mistype/with/same/dirs/here"]
  insteadOf = THERE
```

then, I suppose, the following should work:

```
$ git clone THERE/REPO.git
```